# Union performance with order by

Tags: mysql, union, database-performance

I'm having an performance issue with this `union select` (shorted):

```
SELECT 
    x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d, x.e, x.f, x.g, y.h, y.i
FROM
    x
LEFT JOIN y ON ...

UNION

SELECT
    c.a, c.b, c.c., c.d, c.e, c.f, c.g, d.h, d.i
FROM
    c
LEFT JOIN d ON ...

ORDER BY `ID`, CAST(`X` as UNSIGNED)
```

The query will take up to a second, as I thought because of the `ORDER BY`. But deleting the `ORDER BY` does not have a real performance improvement.

EXPLAIN looks like:

[image]

Anyone has an idea?

Why is this so slow?

Comment: Please, do not post images. They could be broken in future - and the font may be too small. As for your query - I guess that's because you're using `UNION` which is an alias for `UNION DISTINCT` - and so, MySQL is trying to perform sort through entire union row set (and that is done _without_ indexes since it's the same effect as `HAVING`)

Comment: Can you post the full statement that the explain refers to?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
     ORDER BY `ID`
```

and `CAST(`X`as UNSIGNED)` use it when you select `X` not in order by

Comment: I put the CAST to the select statement and references in the `order by` but this will not improve performance, It still takes up to 1 second

Comment: X is is a column. Can i send it to you in chat?

Comment: @frgtv10 i cant delete it manually but ,Just stop using the room. It'll be deleted or frozen (depending on how much it was used) automatically after either 7 or 14 days.Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.